# Is there a library to display a Virtual Human [WPF]

Tags: wpf, animation, 3d, character

While there are a lot of 3D libraries out there, I'm in struggle to find one suitable for WPF.

Basically, I want a Character Animation engine, which loads bone hierarchy and allows me to manipulate the skinned mesh.

I know, this is a classic topic for all the 3D engines. And they are made for building games.

How do I display a Skinned Character in a WPF application?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how broadly you want to distribute your app, provide installation support for it - and how much work you want to do

1)  You can always do it yourself -  but you've probably already decided you don't want to spend 2 years of your life building a render pipeline, learning the vagaries of IK, etc

2) You could target XNA - this is sort of WPF, will run on windows, and the xbox to boot - one package you could consider for XNA is [Visual 3D](http://www.visual3d.net/) - you can find a list of engines [here](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/12882.aspx)

3) IFF you either can access the target machines directly, or can release your app as a standalone WPF application, you've got a lot of options -  all you need is a C# wrapper that allows you to call a native implementation - the one thing you'll loose is WPF ability to superimpose controls, because your render surface will most likely be a winform control embedded in a WPF UI - you will need to get the wrapper DLL into the GAC if you want to distribute the app broadly -

3a) check out the [Blender](http://www.blender.org) community - the entire tool is open source, and there's a lot of smart people playing in that space

4) I'd tout my own engine but it's undergoing a thorough revision and won't be out again for quite a few months -  we'd provide WPF/Silverlight support via option 3 -  .Net wrapper over C++ core directly installed into GAC - which makes it available for WPF/Silverlight - I believe we'll still have to pretend to be a winform control to allow the D3D render surfaces to punch through onto the screen

Hope this helps

PS - one side question - You capitalized Virtual Human --  you aren't referencing the [NIH Visible Human Project](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/visible/visible_human.html), are you ?  If so, last I knew you had to assemble the geometry/bones yourself , all it supplies is the tomagraphic slices

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try this:

[**OGRE Game engine in WPF**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/OgreInTheWpf.aspx)

If that OGRE engine supports bones, you should be good to go.

More about the [OGRE Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OGRE)

Good Luck!

Comment: two times orge instead of ogre!

Comment: I count three heh... it's supposed to be OGRE

Comment: yes ok! I'm a bit dyslexic, and English ain't even my third language.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for skinned meshes in WPF. But you can animate other things like robots well in WPF (see the ape walk example at [www.okino.com](https://www.okino.com/conv/exp_xaml2.htm) ).

You can make meshes deform in WPF by changing the position values. I have done this by creating a control which exposes properties to the WPF animation system. It just takes a lot of effort.

Here is my unfinished WPF app. Notice the ball joints in the robot. The only place I really need mesh deformations is in the face, so she can talk.

Since MS dropped support for WPF 3D in Visual Studio its really hard to make realistic animations. Although with UIElement3D you could write an app that allows you to let people drag the robots limbs around and then take a snapshot. An animation system on top of the WPF animation system.

I have written a plugin for blender which allows you to export 3D models from Blender.

[image: Robot TV]

So if you want to write a skinned mesh for WPF, you will have to write your own. Bones are really just transforms which work on part of the mesh.